# MQTT unable to connect over TLS

Tags: javascript, react-native, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to a MQTT broker over TLS in react-native with [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js). Based on the doc I tried this code:

```js
const options = {
  port: PORT,
  host: HOST,
  protocol: 'mqtts',
  secureProtocol: 'TLS_method',
  username: USERNAME,
  password: PASSWORD,
  ca: CA_FILE
}

const client = mqtt.connect(options);

client.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log("error", error);
});

client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connected");
});
```

The options object will be passed through `tls.connect()`, so I specified the certificate file.

The connection doesn't return an error, but the client is not connected.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you see it even trying to connect in the broker logs?

Comment: is the 'ca: CA_FILE' the actual contents of your cert??    "ca: fs.readFileSync('./cacert.pem')"   And what hardlib said:  What do you see in the MQTT broker log file?

Comment: Yes the CA_FILE is the content, not the path, and the broker log show:
`1595238085: OpenSSL Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown`
`1595238085: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.`
What could cause this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that fork of React native MQTT https://github.com/FrozenPyrozen/rn-native-mqtt it worked with TLS connection on Android and IOS

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30561600)